# How should I start? A rails app to request, receive and store JSon files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I guess I'm a Jr level developer, I don't even have one year experience with coding yet, so I'd appreciate any help and directions you guys could give me. I've worked mainly with Rails, and so far I built some fullstack webapps like blogs or Airbnb-like platforms, but never anything like that:
I'm about to start a project, It'll be a rails app that calls for an API that gives me a JSon as response, I'll need to compress this file and store it in a database. So the flow of the application will be:

- Receive json from API (I already know how to do that from the API documentation)
- Compress it (to reduce the amount of space needed to store those)
- Send it to storage (for now it'll be done locally)

Should I create this app with "rails new 'projectname' --api"? Should I create it as an API, since it won't really need frontend? How should I start? Will I need controllers and models to execute the actions described above?

I'm kinda lost and I would really appreciate any directions to start with. If you guys have done that before, or have any guide or tutorial that could help, maybe a guide to create a similar project, I'd aprecciate any info I can get. I'm searching for a good way to start and do this, but I didn't find any guide that show me what I think I need to do.
Thanks in advance, guys! I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: what you are asking for can be done, but normally it's not done this way. Typically the database stores model instances and these are rendered by a controller as JSON. This gives you much more flexibility to evolve, add columns, associations, etc, vs storing the JSON in the db. A good way to start is to generate a scaffold for a resource using rails generators. It will create the controller and model and give you a leg-up on your app, even if you scrap the scaffold later.

Comment: but I guess I don't want to be able to have this flexibility. I basically want to create an automation, a bot, that makes a request to the API, gets the JSON, compress it and send it to a storage. And I actually want to execute this action from time to time. A friend of mine gave me the idea of not even use controllers, just tasks that execute those actions that I want, and schedule those tasks with Heroku. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve data from an API and store the resulting JSON in a database. You would probably make a rake task to send a request to the API and trigger the rake task with a CRON job. The rake task would not need a controller in order to store the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I made some more research, decided to go with a model and controller, using Active Storage to handle attached files, so the model will have a "has_one_attached :json_file" in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I decided to go with controllers and models.
I created the app as an API, also a ResponsesController and a Response model that has a .json file(that I receive from the API) attached to it.

Comment: I appreciate Les Nightingill response tho, thank you :)